# Чехарда: игра или беспорядок?

Tags: этимология

Есть такая игра - чехарда. Но в то же время это беспорядок, путаница. А что первично: название игры или обозначение беспорядка? И какое происхождение у этого слова?
Спасибо

Answer (score 6):

По Фасмеру ЧЕХАРДА - диал. чегарда, севск. (Преобр.), шигарда, донск. (Миртов1). Древняя форма не установлена достоверно; ср. еще блр. чекорда "ватага детей, куча поросят". Все известные этимологии неудачны...

Но есть и такое слово: ЧЕХОР - "беспокойный человек, забияка", чехорной "задорный, драчливый", арханг. (Подв.), ср. чеш. "дергать, трепать", слвц. "растрепа (о женщине)", "дергать, трепать", польск. сzесhrаc "чесать шерсть, трепать",  "тереть, чесать".

В словаре Даля ЧЕХОР м. арх.-мез. драчун, буян, забияка. Чехорный парень, задорливый и буйный. Чехорда <чехарда>, чекорда, игра, где прыгают друг через дружку. Сесть на кого чехордой, верхом или на закукры. *У него семья чехорда, полна изба ребят. Ходить чехордой, толпой, ватагой.

В. Даль отдельно слово "чехарда" не выделяет, т.е. оно в определении к слову "чехор" так и есть.

Получается, что, скорее всего, "чехарда" от "чехор" (забияка, драчун, беспокойный, шустрый). Потом уже игра, а переносное совсем позднее явление "беспорядок, неразбериха".

Answer (score 4):

У Ожегова: ЧЕХАРДА   1.  Игра,  в  которой  один  из игроков, разбежавшись, перепрыгивает через другого, подставляющего ему для упора согнутую спину. 2. перен.  Частые изменения в чем-н.,  создающие  неопределенное,  неустойчивое положение (разг. неодобр.). Министерская ч. (частая смена министров).

У Шанского: происхождение неясно, наиболее предпочтительное объяснение – суффиксально производное от чехор – драчун, забияка (это решение предлагал еще Даль). Менее убедительным кажется тюркское происхождение слова (сравнить: чих арда (азейбардж.) – вскочи на спину).
Интересно, что Ожегов считает название игры первичным, вследствие чего  тюркское происхождение уже не кажется необоснованным.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю.

Чехарда - не просто некий беспорядок, а вполне конкретный, связанный с постоянными изменениями чего либо связанного или кого-либо сопричастного.

> 1. Неодобр.
>    О путанице, неразберихе, неустойчивости положения ***из-за частых перемещений или изменений где-л***. Началась ч.! Трудно разобраться в этой чехарде!

(БТС Кузнецова; курсив мой, b-s)

С этим уточнением совершенно очевидно, что значение "беспорядок" вторично и порождено первым, названием игры, в которой все прыгают друг через друга.